# Group by category,store and attribute and assign sequence based on alphabetical order of attribute name

Tags: sql, db2

In a DB2 database I have 2 tables

```
  attribute
  ---------
  attribute_id      name
  1002                  xyz
  1012                  abc
  1023                  lmn
  1057                  def
  1076                  qwe

  storecatattrrel
  ---------------
  store_id      category_id      attribute_id
  100                  10007            1012
  100                  10007            1057
  100                  10007            1023
  101                  10005            1002
  101                  10006            1002
  101                  10007            1057
  101                  10007            1002
  101                  10007            1023
  101                  10007            1076
```

I am trying to create an SQL query using which I want to assign sequence value to attributes in category-store-attribute relationship based on alphabetical order of attribute name like below.

```
  store_id      category_id      attribute_id      sequence
  100                  10007            1012              1
  100                  10007            1057              2
  100                  10007            1023              3
  101                  10005            1002              1
  101                  10006            1002              1
  101                  10007            1057              1
  101                  10007            1002              4
  101                  10007            1023              2
  101                  10007            1076              3
```

I tried using ROW_NUMBER function but without any luck.

```
select b.store_id, b.category_id, b.attribute, a.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by attribute_id) from storecatattrrel b
    inner join attribute a on a.attribute_id = b.attribute_id
    order by name asc;
```

I could not find a way to group the results based on store_id, category_id and attribute_id and then assign the sequence.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `order by` and need to fix the `partition by`:

```
select sc.store_id, sc.category_id, sc.attribute, a.name, 
       row_number() over (partition by sc.store_id, sc.category_id 
                          order by a.name
                         ) as sequence
from storecatattrrel sc join
     attribute a
     on a.attribute_id = sc.attribute_id
order by a.name asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is correct just an `order by` clause is missing after `partition by` in generating your `Row_number()`. For more info on this you may find this link [Row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select b.store_id, b.category_id, b.attribute, a.name, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by b.category_id order by a.name) as Slno from storecatattrrel b
    inner join attribute a on a.attribute_id = b.attribute_id
```